# creating a new environment which can insert a tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, environments, tkz-euclide

I am trying to create a new environment in my preamble which will put a space above and below each diagram centre and

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newenvironment{proposition}
{\begin{center}\em}
{\end{center}}

%\newenvironment{diagram}
%\vspace*{\fill}
    %{\begin{center}\em}
    %{\end{center}}
%\vspace*{\fill}

\begin{document}

\begin{proposition}
        On a given finite right line (AB) to construct an equilateral triangle.
 \end{proposition}


%\begin{diagram}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
\tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B} 
\tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
\tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
\tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\end{diagram]

\end{document}
```

I think I am going about the whole thing the wrong way as without the environment it renders fine, any hint? I can't find any examples out there.
I have hidden the bits which mess up the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to center  the `tikzpicture` and adding space before and after.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\newenvironment{proposition}
{\begin{center}\em}
    {\end{center}}


\newenvironment{diagram}
{\begin{center}\vspace*{10pt}\begin{tikzpicture}}
    {\end{tikzpicture}\vspace*{-5pt}\end{center}}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{proposition}
    On a given finite right line (AB) to construct an equilateral triangle.
\end{proposition}
            
\begin{diagram}
        \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A} 
        \tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B} 
        \tkzDrawSegment(A,B) 
        \tkzLabelPoint[left](A){$A$} 
        \tkzLabelPoint[right](B){$B$}
\end{diagram}
    
Some text.
    
\end{document}
```

[image: a]

Comment: Thanks, works great